# Runtime improvement for blending of two numpy 2d arrays in RGBA

Tags: python, numpy, blending, rgba

i am trying to blend two "figures" in form of numpy nd arrays of dimensions (2000,2000,4) with RGBA colorcoding together. I implemented a smooth blending around a threshold value of one of the arrays. Now i need to improve the runtime of this code, since it should picture a live-view of two cameras. Does anybody has a suggestion how i could make this code faster?
An example code is shown here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
from time import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def generate_alpha_map(image: np.ndarray, threshold: float):
    """
    generates an alpha map in the range of 20% above the threshold. The map has the same size as the
    input image, all values below the threshold are 0, the 20% above the threshold are linear
    interpolated on basis of the image values and everything above threshold + 20% is 1.

    :param np.ndarray image: Signal image with values [0,1]
    :param float threshold: Lower edge cutoff value [0,1]
    :return np.ndarray: 2d map with 0 for all elements below cutoff, 1 for all elements above
        threshold+0.2 and linear interpolation on basis of the measured data inbetween
    """
    alpha = np.zeros_like(image, dtype=np.float)
    alpha_mask = np.logical_and(image >= (1-threshold), image <= (1-threshold)+0.2)
    alpha[alpha_mask] = np.interp(image[alpha_mask], ((1-threshold), (1-threshold)+0.2), (0, 1))
    alpha[image > (1-threshold)+0.2] = 1
    alpha[image < (1-threshold)] = 0
    return alpha

cmap_1 = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Spectral')
cmap_2 = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('jet')

colormap_threshold = 0.8

image1 = np.random.rand(2000,2000)
image2 = np.random.rand(2000,2000)

t0=time()

x, y = image2.shape
raw = np.ones([x, y, 4])
alpha = np.zeros_like(image2, dtype=np.float)

# Calculation of alpha map and smooth blending
alpha = generate_alpha_map(image2, colormap_threshold)
raw = cmap_1(image1) * (1-alpha[:, :, None]) \
    + cmap_2(image2) * (alpha[:, :, None])
t1=time()
print(t1-t0)
```

I tried to prevent using the matplotlib cmaps and calculate the three RGB colorchannels individually by a direct look-up-table. However, this results in the same runtime.

Comment: Presumably your alpha map is constant and could be generated outside your timing code.